# Оформление полей

Tags: jquery, forms

Есть обычные input-ы.
Если они пустые бекграунд красный.
Если они не пустые бекграунд серый(тут нужно предусмотреть ввод информации пользователем).
Реализовывал через Jquery но в силу своих начальных знаний не смог справиться с такой, на первый взгляд простой задачей.

Пробовал сделать вот так.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".necessary").val() == ""){
        $(".necessary").css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
        $(".necessary").css("background-color", "green");
    }
});
```

Должен обратить внимание на то, что нужно предусмотреть ввод информации пользователем.
То есть если сначала поле пустое, то когда пользователь ввел какую-то информацию, поле меняет цвет.

Comment: Ну и проблема в чем? Используйте перебор всех полей через `$.each` например.

Comment: Все три (_на данный момент_) ответа идентичны, но в них пропущен один момент. Если будет хоть один пробел, то значение поля уже не будет считаться пустым. Если это для вас важно, то примените метод .trim(), т.е: `$.trim( $(el).val() )`;

Answer (score 2):

Используйте этот код

```
$('input').on('change load', function(){
  $(this).css('background-color': $(this).val() ? 'green' : 'red');
});
```

Comment: По-хорошему нужно еще и событие `input` слушать.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev вы имели в виду `keypress`?

Comment: Нет, я имею в виду именно `input`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input

Comment: Хотя для старых браузеров можно еще и `keypress` добавить =)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev если добавить `keypress` и `input` то функция будет вызываться дважды при каждом нажатии. Не очень красиво. Наверное лучшее решение - это `.on('keypress load')`

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".necessary" ).each( function() {
    $( this ).css("background-color", $( this ).val() == ""? "red" : "green");
} );
```

Либо вообще можно изначально поставить всем полям цвет `green` (в css например), а затем отфильтровать незаполненные и поставить бекграунд только им:

```
$( ".necessary" ).filter( function() {
    return $( this ).val() == "";
} ).css("background-color", "red");
```